# How can I have two content titles?

Tags: pages

I'm facing a design, that has two titles. I have no clue how can I two titles in wordpress.

In a nutshell: Creating a page, there you can set the title. How can I have two titles there? Or similar effect?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking title is column in posts database table so it is not easy (or makes sense) to add one more title.

But it is trivial to emulate by using [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to store additional title (or anything else).

Comment: Yes! Thats the solution I'm looking for. However, I can't seem the custom fields to work. Tried `get_post_custom_values('second_header');`, but nop.

Comment: @Kalle you should use [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: Your correct. I found it out myself, but forgot to put echo in front. Anyways, works perfectly. Saved me lots of valuable time. Thanks alot!